# O(n log n) vs O(m) for algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am finding an algorithm for a problem where I have two sets A and B of points with n and m points. I have two algorithms for the sets with complexity O(n log n) and O(m) and I am now wondering whether the complexity for the both algorithms combined is O(n log n) or O(m).

Basically, I am wondering whether there is some relation between m and n which would result in O(m).

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Unless you use the algorithms together as a single algorithm, then they are just as you have stated: one is O(n log n) and one is O(m). If you were to use them together and call that a single algorithm, then that resulting algorithm would likely be O(n log n) assuming the sets of points are of comprable size as that will dominate the overall wall time.

Comment: @ludask Combined how?

Comment: A real world example would be an algorithm applied to a [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) with `n` vertices and `m` edges.  For a complete graph, `m = n * (n-1) / 2`, so O(m) + O(n log n) is O(m).

Comment: Where did these sets come from? If there's a relation between m and n, it must come from the details of the problem and no-one can answer that for you without knowing the details of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If m and n are truly independent of one another and neither quantity influences the other, then the runtime of running an O(n log n)-time algorithm and then an O(m)-time algorithm is will be O(n log n + m). Neither term dominates the other - if n gets huge compared to m then the n log n part dominates, and if m is huge relative to n then the m term dominates.

This gets more complicated if you know how m and n relate to one another in some way. Many graph algorithms, for example, use m to denote the number of edges and n to denote the number of nodes. In those cases, you can sometimes simplify these expressions, but sometimes cannot. For example, the cost of implementing Dijkstra’s algorithm with a Fibonacci heap is O(m + n log n), the same as what we have above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if `m ~ n^n`, then `O(logm)` = `O(nlogn)`.

There is a log formula:

```
log(b^c) = c*log(b)
```

**EDIT:**

For both the algos combined the [Big O](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/big-o-notation-why-it-matters-and-why-it-doesnt-1674cfa8a23c/) is always the one that is larger because we are concerned about the asymptotic upper bound.
So it will depend on value of `n` and `m`. Eg: While `n^n` < `m`, the complexity is `Olog(m)`, after that it becomes `O(nlog(n))`.
For Big-O notation we are only concerned about the larger values, so if `n^n` >>>> `m` then it is `O(nlog(n))`, else if `m` >>>> `n^n` then it is `O(logm)`

Answer (score 0):

Size of your input is `x: = m + n`.

Complexity of a combined (if both are performed at most a constant number of times in the combined algorithm) algorithm is:
`O(n log n) + O(m) = O(x log x) + O(x) = O(x log x)`.

Comment: While this is true, it provides a looser bound on the runtime than O(m + n log n) because it doesn’t differentiate how the runtime is more sensitive to the n term than the m term.